# Как из Part получить содержимое файла xml?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, fileupload

У меня есть форма на фронте, я отправляю там файл XML на сервер. На сервере его принимаю вот так:

```
List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "openFile".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());


schemaService.schemaCommit(fileParts);
```

В сервлете я пытаюсь получить содержание XML в виде строки:

```
public void schemaCommit(List<Part> fileParts) throws IOException {
        for (Part filePart : fileParts) {

            String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString((File) filePart, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

ну и потом это все закидываю в БД:

```
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                    "insert into SCHEMAS VALUE (ID, DOCUMENT, COLLECTION) values(3, XMLType(?), 1) ");
            query.setParameter(1, xml);
            query.executeUpdate();
}
}
```

Вот такую ошибку выдает:

```
class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem cannot be cast to class java.io.File (org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @2b3273dc; java.io.File is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

В целом, я примерно таким образом файлы картинок в БД закидываю, но там `Part` залетает целиком, вместе с мета информацией. А тут нужно как-то выгрести именно само содержимое. Уже один день убил на поиски решения(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кастить к  `File` нельзя, потому что это не файл. Попробуй следующее

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(filePart.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Вау, я даже не думал что будет такое короткое и элегантное решение. Спасибо! Работает)